# Removing smaller terms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So I have a expression like `Sin@a*Cos@b+Sin@a*Sin@b+Sin@a`, Which I would like to remove the smaller terms like Sin@a*Sin@b ,and keep the larger ones. In this expression, a and b are both smaller terms. Normal would not work in this case.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to do a series expansion and then keep only the linear terms, like this:

```
f = Sin@a*Cos@b + Sin@a*Sin@b + Sin@a;
poly = Series[f, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] // Normal

(*  a (2 + b)  *)
```

We convert the polynomial to its `CoefficientRules` form and then `Select` only the rules whose exponents add up to one or less:

```
c = CoefficientRules[poly, {a, b}]

{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 2}

s = Select[c, Total@(#[[1]]) <= 1 &]

{{1, 0} -> 2}
```

Finally, convert the selected rules back to polynomial form:

```
FromCoefficientRules[s, {a, b}]

(*  2 a  *)
```

Comment: Similar but avoiding the double series: `Normal[
  Series[f /. Thread[{a, b} -> t*{a, b}], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1

Out[27]= 2 a + a b` (And same idea with series taken to first rather than second order to obtain `2*a`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a,b are small of equal order substituting `a->eps a, b-> eps b`

```
 Normal[Series[f /. {a -> eps a, b -> eps b}, {eps, 0, 3}] ] /. eps -> 1
 (*2 a - a^3/3 + a b - (a b^2)/2*)
```

gives the result

Comment: This is a very general and useful technique that I use a lot